# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-neptune

I am trying to query the **Neptune** data-processing awscurl API from the EC2 instance mentioned in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/machine-learning-on-graphs-processing.html). While querying this I am getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/awscurl", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscurl/awscurl.py", line 521, in main
    inner_main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscurl/awscurl.py", line 509, in inner_main
    allow_redirects=args.location)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscurl/awscurl.py", line 142, in make_request
    return __send_request(uri, data.encode('utf-8'), headers, method, verify, allow_redirects)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscurl/awscurl.py", line 348, in __send_request
    response = requests.request(method, uri, headers=headers, data=data, verify=verify, allow_redirects=allow_redirects)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='neptunedbcluster-abc.cluster-xyz.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ml/dataprocessing (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4aa7de2710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Comment: This looks like your notebook does not have access to the cluster.  Can you try to status API to see if you are able to connect?  https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/status. If you cannot then you should look at your VPC and Security group setups

Comment: @bechbd FYI, This call is from the EC2 instance. I have checked the status of the Neptune using %status in a notebook. Which is correctly working.

Comment: Can you try issuing an `awscurl` call to the status endpoint from the EC2 instance?  I suspect that your EC2 instance cannot reach Neptune due to the VPC/Security Groups you have configured for your EC2 instance.

Comment: @bechbd I am issuing awscurl call only as follow:
`awscurl -X POST https://neptunedbcluster-abc.cluster-xyz.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com/ml/dataprocessing -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"inputDataS3Location":"s3://graphdata-bucket/neptune-export/20211210_112616/","processedDataS3Location":"s3://graphdata-bucket/netune-data-processing-output/","configFileName":"training-job-configuration.json"}'`

Comment: You are missing the port (8182 by default) on your `awscurl` command.  By default you would use `https://neptunedbcluster-abc.cluster-xyz.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/ml/dataprocessing`